# Google Map Div Display:None || Display:Block JavaScript (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have spent most of the day trying to figure out this simple problem, but still no luck.

### Solved

Here's the background.

As we all know, on the page load of generating the Google Map without being tucked into a hidden DIV has the proper rendering.  However, after generating the Google Map and hiding it behind a Display:None command removes the properties and needs to be reset and recentered.  I've tried playing with code in an assortment of ways and making a global variable or two, but still the Google Map seems to have this issue after reopening the Block - it is centered to the upper left corner of the DIV and the map only renders after the browser window changes.

The ideal situation is to have the DIV element update with the button onclick event and **not** the browser window change.

The maps work ideal when not resized or hidden after generating.

Also, I want the size to truly be zero and then only open the block after clicking the button, then going back to zero after clicking the toggle button again.

I'm not going to include all HTML Code, it can be isolated to this code:

### Solved. Tested. Works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<style type="text/css">

/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the DIV element that contains the map. */

#map_1 {height: 100%;} /* #[element name or ID] */
html {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

    }


body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

</style>
</head>
<body>


DIV IS BELOW THIS LINE<br />
<div id="map_1" style="display:none"></div> 
<!-- Make sure the ID cross references to the defined style -->
<!-- Make sure to at least manually define via px the height if not defining the % height of the html and body -->
DIV IS ABOVE THIS  LINE

<script>
var var_map_1 = null; //Create global variable for map #1

    function initMap()
        {
            var_map_1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_1'),
            {
                center: {
                            lat: 51.433373,
                            lng: -.712251
                        },
                zoom: 15
            });
        }


</script>
    




<!-- Button Javascript ID is >> showhide_map_1 << copy and update flowthrough variable ID if using more than one map -->
<button id="showhide_map_1" onclick="showhide()">Show Map</button>


<script>
function showhide() 
    {
        if (
// Update map DIV variable ID per unique instance
            document.getElementById('map_1').style.display === 'none')
                {
                    document.getElementById('map_1').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('map_1').style.height = '300px';
// Update map VAR variable ID per unique instance, must indicate which variable to resize
                    google.maps.event.trigger(var_map_1, 'resize');
// Must then specify the go to when this re-center line is executed
                    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.433373, -0.712251);
                    var_map_1.panTo(latLng);
// Must then specify the zoom when this re-center line is executed
                    var_map_1.setZoom(15);
// Update the button for simple style
                    document.getElementById("showhide_map_1").innerHTML = "Hide Map";
                }
        else
            {
                document.getElementById('map_1').style.display = 'none';
// Update the button for simple style
                document.getElementById("showhide_map_1").innerHTML = "Show Map";
            }
    }
</script>



    <script  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDzCyw9LDNMsZD6IzqWmm8bij5Av-iE9HA&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use `innerHTML=""` to respective div instead of show hide. while using show hide problem is same as  above

Answer (score 0):

So, per the API defining the coordinates and the zoom is required. However, the coordinates are virtually irrelevant since by default has the setup of being hidden behind a hidden DIV element. As you will see, the code is more so edited to have the ability for more than one map on the same webpage. Key observations are the need to define the map variable for the resize function, use the lastLng as depicted above, then via map name set the zoom.

Here is a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/rt01100111/a9rkeqxf/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<style type="text/css">

/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the DIV element that contains the map. */

#map_1 {height: 100%;} /* #[element name or ID] */
html {height: 100%; margin: 0;padding: 0;}
body {height: 100%; margin: 0;padding: 0;}
</style></head>
<body>

DIV IS BELOW THIS LINE<br />

<div id="map_1" style="display:none"></div> 

<!-- Make sure the ID cross references to the defined style -->
<!-- Make sure to at least manually define via px the height if not defining the % height of the html and body -->

DIV IS ABOVE THIS  LINE

<script>
var var_map_1 = null; //Create global variable for map #1
        function initMap()
        {
            var_map_1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_1'),
            {center: {lat: 51.433373, lng: -.712251}, zoom: 15});}
</script>    

<!-- Button Javascript ID is >> showhide_map_1 << copy and update flowthrough variable ID if using more than one map -->
<button id="showhide_map_1" onclick="showhide()">Show Map</button>

<script>
function showhide() 
    {if (
// Update map DIV variable ID per unique instance
                document.getElementById('map_1').style.display === 'none')
                {document.getElementById('map_1').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('map_1').style.height = '300px';
// Update map VAR variable ID per unique instance, must indicate which variable to resize
                google.maps.event.trigger(var_map_1, 'resize');
// Must then specify the go to when this re-center line is executed
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.433373, -0.712251);
                var_map_1.panTo(latLng);
// Must then specify the zoom when this re-center line is executed
                var_map_1.setZoom(15);
// Update the button for simple style
                document.getElementById("showhide_map_1").innerHTML = "Hide Map";
                }else{
                document.getElementById('map_1').style.display = 'none';
// Update the button for simple style
                document.getElementById("showhide_map_1").innerHTML = "Show Map";}}
</script>

        <script  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDzCyw9LDNMsZD6IzqWmm8bij5Av-iE9HA&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>


  </body>
</html>
```